# How to stop taking input in MIPS at -1?

Tags: assembly, input, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to take in number input for an array in MIPS but I want it to stop when the user would enter -1. I know I have to use 'beq' but I can't understand how. For example 1 2 3 4 5 6 -1

I am working in MARS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For MARS) `beq $s, imm, LABEL` means go to LABEL if `$s == imm`. You must have a loop that keeps asking for the user input. All you have to do is branch to a `LABEL` outside of this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Most assembler languages will require you to first compare the input value with a known value, then jump if the result is zero (i.e., they compared equal).

So it will be something like:

```
loop:
    ; input number here into r7

    cmp r7, -1      ; compare it with -1
    beq exit_loop   ; if equal, exit loop

    ; use r7 here

    bra loop        ; go get next number

exit_loop:
    ; carry on
```

That's in pseudo-asm since a lot of MIPS stuff tends to be classwork and you should be doing *some* of the work yourself :-) Finding the equivalent instructions should be relatively easy.